# Network settings in Openstack with single OpenVPN connection

Tags: networking, kubernetes, openstack, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to set up an Openstack environment with two Kubernetes clusters, one `production` and one `testing`. My idea was to separate them with two networks in Openstack and then have a VPN in front, to limit the exposure through floating ip:s (for this I would have a proxy that routes requests into the correct internal addresses).

However, issues arise when trying to tunnel requests to both networks when connected to the VPN. Either I choose to run the VPN in its own network or in one of the two, but I don't seem to be able to make requests across network boundaries.

Is there a better way to configure the networking in Openstack or OpenVPN, so that I can keep the clusters separated and still have access to all resources through one installation of OpenVPN?

Is it better to run everything in the same Openstack network and separate them with subnets? Can I still have the production and test cluster expose different IP-addresses externally? Are they still separated enough to limit the risk of them accessing each other?

Sidenote: I use Terraform to deploy the infrastructure and Ansible to install resources, if someone has suggestion in the line of already prepared scripts.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went for was to separate the environments with their own networks and cidr and then attach them to the VPN instance to let it get access to them. From there I just tunnel everything.